# JFBConnect and jfbclogin module in joomla 3

Tags: php

Hi everyone I've been used JFBConnect in joomla ver 1.5 and jfbclogin module but I am migrating in joomla version 3 the jfbclogin module are not working. Any idea will appreciated and if there an alternative to this jfbclogin module. Thanks

Comment: Assuming you have a current license for JFBConnect and you are trying to install the correct version for Joomla 3.x, it is probably best to ask for support directly from the developer and/or check out the SourceCoast support forums. You may elicit better or improved answers here if you can describe what you have tried and what the results are (e.g. at what point you see an error message and what the error message is, for example).

Comment: Sorry -1 because this question needs more details regarding versions installed and what exactly the problem is. Currently this question is too vague.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell.

It's most likely still using old deprecated and removed code that Joomla 3.x doesn't support. The only thing you can do is check the developer site to see if there is a Joomla 3.x compatible version of the modue, else find an alternative extension with similar features.

### Update:

According to the developer site, the later versions support Joomla 2.5 and 3.x, however I'm aware this is a commercial extension therefore you may not wish to purchase it. Perhaps someone else who has used a similar extension could provide an alternative if need be.

Comment: Hi Lodder thank you for the time answering and giving a idea about my question.

Comment: Lodder is correct. JFBConnect has versions specifically for Joomla3. If you are using the Joomla1.5 version on a Joomla3 site then it will not work. You will need to install the JFBConnect version that is made specifically for Joomla 3. If you have already done that then it is likely you've found a bug or similar gremlin.<- The best course in that situation is to contact the developer.